# Sql error occurred when I'm trying this query

Tags: mysql

Here is the query

```
 $query_order = "select * from orders where key = '$pay_key'";
```

Error shown

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM `orders` 
where `key` = 'C90320'

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key = 'C90320'' at line 1*
```

Comment: Can you please show more code.  What you are showing right now does not show how the word `key` is getting escaped

Answer (score 1):

`key` is a reserved word. Change your query to:

```
$query_order = "select * from orders where `key` = '$pay_key'";
```

Also, I would recommend escaping the `$pay_key`'s value. Say something like:

```
$pay_key = mysqli_real_escape_string($pay_key);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query_order = "select * from orders 
                 where `key` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($pay_key)."'";
```

Comment: There is one fundamental mistake in your answer now.

Comment: ok one was using deprecated mysql_ extension , please point other

Comment: That's it to my knowledge... :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

first of all you need to compare it using string so code should like this

```
 $query_order = "select * from orders where `key` = '".$pay_key."'";
```

Comment: Also, **Variable parsing** 

When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables are parsed within it.